# ADFS 3.0 location (intranet or extranet) deciscion

Tags: windows, single-sign-on, saml, adfs3.0

Hi Stackoverflow Community!

I have searched through all msdn documentation and asked Dr. Google, but I did not find out how ADFS 3.0 und W2k12r2 does decide if a request is coming from the intranet or extranet zone.

Right now I have setup an ADFS 3.0 server with a custom Authentication Provider and all the time I get the forms page for authentication.

How does the ADFS service decide if the request is coming from the intranet or extranet location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the request goes through the web application proxy server (essentially internet facing ADFS proxy), then it is considered to extranet when it flows to ADFS. This governs the authentication policy and what ADFS does. By default requests inside the network use windows integrated authentication and outside the network, we use forms authentication.

For Office 365, there is some special logic called client access policies as older Outlook clients even inside the network authenticate from the extranet (Exchange Online does this). We have some special handling for that based on IP address.

Hope that helps. 
Thanks
//Sam (@MrADFS)

Comment: Thanks Sam! As I am only using ADFS for SAML authentication the app is not accessed through the web application proxy and therefore all requests are considered as intranet. Is there also an option to use WAP access for SAML?